# Change cell background color onEdit based on value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I change the cell background color based on the cell's content in an `onEdit()` function?

I've had many versions of code that I tested for this - some working almost right, some not working at all.
But I have yet to get this to work the way I need it to.

Please forgive the lack of elegance in the way that this is written, but I actually need to keep the code as straightforward as possible since there will be many cell changes, many conditionals, and many differing numbers of cells that will be changed depending on what gets changed on the worksheet.

Ok, so here goes...

```
function onEdit(event)
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");   
 var changedCell= event.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();

 if (changedCell == 'B3') {
 var c = ss.getRange("B3").getValue();
  if (c < 2); {
  ss.getRange("B3").setBackgroundColor('#ff0000');  
  ss.getRange("B12").setBackgroundColor('#ff0000'); 
  }
  if (c > 1); {
  ss.getRange("B3").setBackgroundColor('#000000');  
  ss.getRange("B12").setBackgroundColor('#000000'); 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to note

1.The name of the method is `setBackground` and not `setBackgroundColor`

2.How is the cell B3 formatted. The comparison works only if it is formatted as an integer. In most cases, Google Spreadsheet automatically formats the cells based on the data type, but if I'm writing code, I'd double check. So use something like

```
 var c = parseInt(ss.getRange("B3").getValue()) ;
```

3.The semicolon is not needed after the `if` condition. That will terminate the if condition immediately. So use

```
if (c < 2) {
```

and

```
if (c > 1) {
```

4.Finally, I don't know how data comes into B3, but if you have 1.5 in B3, then both the `if` conditions become true and your background color is overwritten. So, I suggest that you use a if..elseif

For better readability, I'd use `setBackground('red')` and `setBackground('white')` for the common colours.

Comment: Re 1 - although it's no longer in the docs or autocomplete, `setBackgroundColor` still works.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for setting me straight on the use of the semicolons. I think I might have added them just to see if that would help, but I admit that I wasn't really clear on their purpose, so I was grasping. Btw I've only recently come to realize that searching for GAS solutions tends to return very little in the way of useful info. Case in point would be "parseInt". A google search of "google apps script and parseInt" returned nothing useful except for 1(!) link to a w3schools reference to javascript. Obviously I need to be spending more time searching javascript resources instead. Thanks Srik!

Comment: @Mogsdad - I had found "setBackgroundColor" used somewhere, and it actually did work for me. But I had no idea that it is now out of vogue in GAS. Btw, I received an email from googlecode in regard the validation issue: "data validation is still an open feature request we are in the process of implementing. The methods were accidentally made public while the work on the feature was still in progress. Therefore, we recommend not coding against this pre-released API, as it is possible it may be changed". Now you see it, now you don't... I guess.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the advice from Srik, you should consider the efficiency of your `onEdit()` function. The general idea is to determine whether you should bail out as soon and as cheaply as possible, and then optimize the rest of the code according to the [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) (minimize Service calls, mainly).

It looks like you want the `onEdit()` to perform only on "Sheet2", but the way you have written it, it will trigger for a change on *any sheet*, but mess around with colors on "Sheet2". (Not a visible problem, since the conditions on "Sheet2" are the ones being used to decide on coloring, but you'll be burning up script execution time needlessly.) By using the `event` info to figure out what sheet has been updated, and exiting if it's not "Sheet2", the cost of the `onEdit()` drops.

I agree with Srik about the `if` statements... I just can't tell what you wanted. I don't think the suggestion of `else if` alone will solve it, though, because it would treat `c > 1` as `c > 2`... if you wanted that, why not write it? Maybe you wanted no color for `1 < c < 2`, with red for `c < 1` and black for `c > 2`? You should sort out the logic in that part.

Here's how an optimized `onEdit()` would look, making maximum use of the `event` info:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  if (ss.getName() !== "Sheet2") return; // Get out quickly
  var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var changedCellA1 = changedCell.getA1Notation();
  if (changedCellA1 !== 'B3') return;

  var c = event.value;  // We know we edited cell B3, just get the value
  var background = 'white'; // Assume 1 <= c <= 2
  if (c > 2) {
    background = 'red';
  }
  else if (c < 1) {
    background = 'black'; 
  }
  changedCell.setBackground(background);
  ss.getRange("B12").setBackground(background);
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I cribbed the OnEdit from somewhere. And as usual, I wasn't finding basic stripped-down info; I actually had to parse it out of a complex process that was well beyond my comprehension. I know that you like to hawk the google developers documentation, but I find it largely disappointing and wanting. I just don't seem to learn well from that resource - which is the polar opposite of vba resources, which I seem to find quite easily. Thankfully I learn a lot here... although I usually don't ask until I've already burned myself out pursuing endless dead-ends. Anyway, thanks!