# How to change color of Cell depending on value change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an automatically updating spreadsheet that updates different price values.

How could I set up Conditional Formatting so that if the value in the cell raises, the cell turns green. And if it gets lowered, the cell turns red. And optionally, if the cell doesn't change at all, it stays white.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Use Color scale to format the spreadsheet automatically https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: @WaqarAhmad Not exactly what I'm looking for. After looking into it, it seems as though I need to store the old data of the cell in a different cell when it changes, and then compare the two cells. Any tips for that?

Comment: Are you updating the spreadsheet with Apps Script? You can compare both values before updating and the use [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) method

Comment: To build off @ocordova, you can get the new and old values using `onEdit(e)`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

Comment: @TiffanyG.Wilson I understand that the spreadsheet is updated automatically (assuming from a function) in that case the onEdit won't be fired, right?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the recommendations in comment, you should consider using the [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) function that runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. It use the information in the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to respond appropriately.

Found this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561753/5832311) which suggested to use if statements.

> Sample code:
>
> ```
> function onEdit(event)
> {
>   var ss = event.range.getSheet();
>   if (ss.getName() !== "Sheet2") return; // Get out quickly
>   var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
>   var changedCellA1 = changedCell.getA1Notation();
>   if (changedCellA1 !== 'B3') return;
>
>   var c = event.value;  // We know we edited cell B3, just get the value
>   var background = 'white'; // Assume 1 <= c <= 2
>   if (c > 2) {
>     background = 'red';
>   }
>   else if (c < 1) {
>     background = 'black'; 
>   }
>   changedCell.setBackground(background);
>   ss.getRange("B12").setBackground(background);
> }
> ```

You can also check these related links:

- [Google Spreadsheet: Script to Change Row Color when a cell changes text;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703676/google-spreadsheet-script-to-change-row-color-when-a-cell-changes-text)
- [Google Spreadsheet: Script to change background color of a cell based on a hex code in the neighboring cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766943/google-spreadsheet-script-to-change-background-color-of-a-cell-based-on-a-hex-ct)

Hope this helps!